# How do I set Chrome to use a period as a decimal instead of a comma?

Tags: html, google-chrome, numbers, locale, decimal-point

The following HTML5 code works. It allows a user to capture decimals using the HTML5 type="number" input type. This is made possible by the step attribute:

```
<input value="" name="turnover" id="turnover" placeholder="0" type="number" step="0.01">
```

The problem is that in South Africa, we use a period (.) as a decimal and not a comma (,). Unfortunately, Chrome is not allowing the use of a period and forces the user to use a comma. Apparently some other browsers use whatever decimal separator you use in the step attribute. Seems not Chrome.

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the `lang` attribute of that input element to that of a country where periods denote decimals instead of comma, eg. english (en)

```
<input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" lang="en">
```

Comment: this is actually very usefull to test your application!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the culture code of the page? Assuming your site serves mainly South African visitors...?

Comment: @MarkvanWyk hmm, apologies I thought I remembered coming across this but not as well as I thought I did apparently. I did manage to find this (setting language); http://nimbupani.com/declaring-languages-in-html-5.html and this (input patterns - near the bottom); http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/html5-forms-pt2.html but I don't think it answers your question - sorry :-(

Comment: I'm going to try and set the Apache settings to return locale information in the header. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest solution I could come up which achieves the same effect. It uses the text attribute with a regular expression via the pattern attribute, instead of the HTML5 number attribute.

**For currency (or 2 decimal places):**

```
<input type="text" value="0" name="turnover" placeholder="0" pattern="\d+(\.\d{2})?"/>
```

**For scientific (or 6 decimal places)**

```
<input type="text" value="0" name="turnover" placeholder="0" pattern="\d+(\.\d{6})?"/>
```

**For any decimal places**

```
<input type="text" value="0" name="turnover" placeholder="0" pattern="\d+(\.\d+)?"/>
```

Hope this helps. If you have a better solution, please post!

Comment: The pattern attribute only seems to be considered on form submission and not directly. I also would like to allow scientific notation like "1.5e-4". Therefore, "e,E,+,-" should be valid characters.